# change background color of div on button click

Tags: c#, html, css

In my code behind i am generating html string

```
<a href='#' class='my-post' onclick='myFunc(" + Id + ")'>
     <div class='my-idea'>
        <span >23</span>
        <span class='heart'></span>
     </div>
</a>
```

I have implemented `myFunc` function in code behind as below

```
funcString += "function myFunc(id){";
funcString += "document.getElementById(\"" + btn1.ClientID + "\").click();"; 
funcString += "}";
```

Then on `btn1` click event i do some processing

```
protected void btnSubmitWinnerPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // some processing
    }
```

Now i want to change background color of div inside that href tag when button is clicked. How can i achieve?

Comment: You can add a css class with the needed color. Then on click you add / remove that class and then resend you html. But i think something in JQuery will be better in your case.

You can do the same thing in JQuery but you don't have to call your server and reload.

See the jquery function addClass / removeClass

Comment: @Guillaume Beauvois: Yea, except two things: First, jQuery is slow, so don't use it. Second, "protected void btnSubmitWinnerPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)" indicates he uses asp.net with postbacks, so JavaScript won't get him very far (it reloads the page after the click - HTTP form-post on click, that's how asp.net works)...

Answer (score 0):

Add runat server to your div, and give it an ID.

```
  <div runat="server" id="mydiv">

    </div>
```

Then you can add the background color in the codebehind, like this:

```
this.mydiv.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF00FF");
```

If you add the background-color with JavaScript, e.g. like this:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.background = "#FF00FF";
```

Then it will be removed because the postback on the postback-click-event reloads the page after your JS function has changed the page...

By the way, if you use .NET 4.0, you can use clientidmode="Static" so you don't need

```
document.getElementById("<%=btn1.ClientID %>").click();
```

like so

```
<div runat="server" id="mydiv" clientidmode="Static">
```

I would also recommend you do your processing with AJAX (jQuery AJAX + ashx-handler + JSON, not ms-ajax controls) instead of with postbacks. 
If you use postbacks, the speed and usability of your site will most-likely be terrible.

Comment: problem is that i have2 more divs. so i can identify which div is want to change color because click event is same for all div

Answer (score 0):

You can use Page.RegisterStartupScript to add your script to change the background color from your code behind event "protected void btnSubmitWinnerPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)"

if you use jQuery, then use $('.my-idea').css('background-color', 'blue') to change the background color of the div